# MS Access how to delete all records in a table and insert new records in that table without deleting the table first

Tags: ms-access

Info: Today I use a SELECT INTO query in a MS Access database to generate table A. In MS Access I export this table A monthly to a SharePoint List to publish the data.

My question is:
I want to use a linked table A (not an exported table).
That means I can't use SELECT INTO anymore because the SELECT INTO first deletes the linked table A and then generates a new table A. This new table is no longer linked.
How can I replace all content in the linked table A with new data without deleting the table first?

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run two different query:

The first one allow you to delete all records in table A so your table is empty:

```
DELETE * FROM tableA
```

The second one allow you to populate table A with new values from table B (for example):

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, fiel3, ...) SELECT field1, field2, field3 ... FROM tableB WHERE ...
```

This can be done by vba (for example on button's click):

```
Dim sql1 as string
Dim sql2 as string

sql1 = "DELETE * FROM tableA"
sql2 = "INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, fiel3, ...) SELECT field1, field2, field3 ... FROM tableB WHERE ..."

Docmd.RunSQL sql1
Docmd.RunSQL sql2
```

or you can create two different query and run the **delete query** first and than your **insert into** query.

Comment: Thank you, I made a macro with the delete and append query. Simple and it works fine for me.